# sql join - only select top row from 2nd table

Tags: sql, join, distinct, distinct-values

Bit of an sql noob, have a list in table a of customercodes/phone numbers, and table b has all the call records.

I want to select the most recent call from table b for each of the customercodes/phone numbers in table a.

So far I have:

```
SELECT     A.CustomerCode, A.PhoneNumber, B.StartTime
FROM         tableA A INNER JOIN
             tableB B ON ( A.PhoneNumber = B.PhoneNumber 
                           AND A.CustomerCode = B.CustomerCode )
ORDER BY A.CustomerCode, A.CLI, B.StartTime DESC
```

But that is bringing up all the results from TableB. I literally just want to get the most recent call if that makes sense?

Answer (score 6):

You can join the calls table on itself, and specify that no later row may exist.  Like:

```
SELECT       A.CustomerCode, A.PhoneNumber, B.StartTime
FROM         tableA A 
INNER JOIN   tableB B 
ON           A.PhoneNumber = B.PhoneNumber 
AND          A.CustomerCode = B.CustomerCode
LEFT JOIN    tableB later
ON           B.PhoneNumber = later.PhoneNumber 
AND          B.CustomerCode = later.CustomerCode
AND          later.StartTime > B.StartTime
WHERE        later.PhoneNumber is null
```

The condition `later.PhoneNumber is null` says there can't be a later row.  If there are multiple rows with the same StartTime, this will select all of them.

This allows you to select all columns from the latest call.

Answer (score 4):

If you only want the starttime from table b, you could use a group by

```
SELECT     A.CustomerCode, A.PhoneNumber, max(B.StartTime)
FROM         tableA A INNER JOIN
             tableB B ON A.PhoneNumber = B.PhoneNumber 
                         AND A.CustomerCode = B.CustomerCode
GROUP BY A.CustomerCode, A.PhoneNumber
ORDER BY A.CustomerCode, A.CLI
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT A.CustomerCode, A.PhoneNumber, Max(B.StartTime) AS MaxOfStartTime
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.PhoneNumber = B.PhoneNumber
GROUP BY A.CustomerCode, A.PhoneNumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.CustomerCode, A.PhoneNumber, B.StartTime
FROM   tableA A INNER JOIN tableB B 
       ON A.PhoneNumber = B.PhoneNumber AND A.CustomerCode = B.CustomerCode
WHERE  B.StartTime = (SELECT MIN(StartTime) FROM B 
                      WHERE PhoneNumber = A.PhoneNumber 
                      AND CustomerCode = A.CustomerCode)
ORDER BY A.CustomerCode, A.CLI, B.StartTime DESC
```

I believe this will give your desired result, provided B.StartTime is *unique* in the set related to each row from table A. If you're dealing with a DateTime and events not too close together, this should be reliable.

The only other way I know is using CROSS APPLY in MSSQL 2005+