# Select Top row of 2nd table in SQL Join

Tags: sql, join

I have to tables called `USERS` and `COMM_HISTORY`

```
USERS(user_id, name)
COMM_HISTORY(comm_history_id, comm_date, comm_by, user_id)
```

`USERS` table will have a unique list of users and `COMM_HISTORY` can have duplicates of `user_id`. When I join them I would like to grab the name of user and the most recent `comm_date` from `COMM_HISTORY`.

Something similar with this post [sql join - only select top row from 2nd table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819003/sql-join-only-select-top-row-from-2nd-table) but it seems there's no correct answers in that post.

I would like to have the ff result when I join them

```
1 John Doe 2012-01-29 Jane Doe
```

Instead of

```
1 John Doe 2011-10-20 Jane Lee
2 John Doe 2012-01-29 Jane Doe
3 John Doe 2011-09-08 Jane Doe
```

Anyone has a solution for this?

Comment: **What** database and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems - SQL is **NOT** a database product... stuff like this is very often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what database system you're using....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Andomar's solution in the other question should work. Adapted to your use case, it would be:

```
SELECT USERS.*, COMM_HISTORY.*
FROM USERS
INNER JOIN COMM_HISTORY
  ON USERS.user_id = COMM_HISTORY.user_id 
LEFT JOIN COMM_HISTORY LATER_HISTORY
  ON COMM_HISTORY.user_id = LATER_HISTORY.user_id 
  AND LATER_HISTORY.comm_date > COMM_HISTORY.comm_date
WHERE LATER_HISTORY.user_id IS NULL
```

Join the history table back onto itself, and set a condition saying no later history rows should be selected.

Answer (score 0):

an approach using cte

```
with recent_comms as (
select 
   row_number() over (partition by user_id, order by comm_date decs) as rn,
   comm_date,
   comm_by, 
   user_id 
FROM comm_history)

select 
   users.name, 
   recent_comms.comm_date, 
   recent_comms.comm_by
from users
join recent_comms on users.user_id = recent_comms.user_id
and recent_comms.rn = 1
```

changing the rn = 1 to rn <= 5 would get the last 5 per user, for example.