# Limiting SQL Join to only first 3 items in joined table

Tags: common-table-expression, join

consider this CTE

```
;WITH Columns AS 
(
    SELECT object_id AS TableId, Name AS ColumnName 
    FROM SYS.columns
), 
Tables AS 
(
    SELECT S.NAME AS SchemaName, T.NAME AS TableName, object_id AS TableId
    FROM sys.tables T
    INNER JOIN  sys.schemas S ON S.schema_id = T.schema_id
)
SELECT T.SchemaName, T.TableName, C.ColumnName
FROM Tables T
INNER JOIN Columns C ON T.TableId = C.TableId
```

What I want to do is to limit the results of the columns to only be the first three (say ordered alphabetically for example)

So if I have 1 schema (e.g. dbo) with 2 tables TableX & TableY with 4 cols each ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD my results would be
something like

```
  dbo   TableX    ColA
  dbo   TableX    ColB
  dbo   TableX    ColC
  dbo   TableY    ColA
  dbo   TableY    ColB
  dbo   TableY    ColC
```

schema_a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I found answer :-)

[Select Top row of 2nd table in SQL Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9061344/select-top-row-of-2nd-table-in-sql-join)

```
;WITH Columns AS 
(
    SELECT 
        row_number() over (partition by object_id ORDER BY Name DESC) as RowNumber,
        object_id AS TableId, 
        Name AS ColumnName 
    FROM SYS.columns
), 
Tables AS 
(
    SELECT 
        S.NAME AS SchemaName, 
        T.NAME AS TableName, object_id AS TableId
    FROM sys.tables T
    INNER JOIN  sys.schemas S ON S.schema_id = T.schema_id
)
SELECT T.SchemaName, T.TableName, C.RowNumber, C.ColumnName
FROM Tables T
INNER JOIN Columns C ON T.TableId = C.TableId
where RowNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 3
```

Comment: Serves me right for not checking SO properly. The answer popped up in the 'related' list as soon as refreshed the page. But that question is slightly different so I don't think this is quite a duplicate.